# Проблема с доменом и GitHub Pages

Tags: веб-программирование, github, dns, github-pages

Возникла следующая проблема
Заказчик купил хостинг, и попросил перенести сайт с мини изменениями. До этого у другого разработчика сайт хостился на GitHub Pages. Перенёс файлы, подключил домен. Предыдущий разраб отключил сайт на гитхабе, но при попытке зайти на сайт, перебрасывает на страницу с ошибкой 404. There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.
Первый раз такое вижу, что делать, в документации ничего не нашёл (возможно плохо искал). Пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: что-что делать, dns настраивать...

Comment: 1 - "Предыдущий разраб отключил сайт на гитхабе, но при попытке зайти на сайт" - соответственно, нужно включить сайт на гитхабе, 2 - в настройках pages настроить сторонний домен.